# filtering based on user inputs in Shiny is not work

Tags: r, shiny

User new to Shiny here. It is a very easy mode. But it's not work and it doesn't show any errors.

The same result when I use subset function.

Here's my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("variable", "Variable:",colnames(iris))
        ),

        mainPanel(
            tableOutput("table")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$table <- renderTable({
        
        iris %>% dplyr::filter(input$variable>=5)
        
        
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input$variable` is a character you can use `.data` pronoun here to use it as column value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      varSelectInput("variable", "Variable:",iris)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderTable({
    iris %>% dplyr::filter(.data[[input$variable]]>=5)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks and it's work. And I find a better way to figure out [link](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.5.0/varSelectInput.html) . Using rlang::!!()